# How do I shorten a flex item in a form without breaking the layout?

Tags: html, forms, css, flexbox

I'm creating a mobile-first responsive website using forms. This is the desired mockup I need to create after 769px.

[image]

Under *contact information*, How do I shorten the zip input as they have it, while also keeping it in the same place using flexbox?

Is it not possible to do this using solely flexbox properties, or would I have to do something else such as apply a position property to it?

I set the `flex-grow` property for the rest of the containers properly, but I know I have to do something for the last flex container. Below is my HTML and CSS code for this project.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: seashell;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

.header-content {
  text-align: center;
  background: #29405a;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #29405a;
}

.signup {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px #29405a dashed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

form {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: #feffff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.field {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px red solid;
}


/*input styles*/

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
textarea,
select {
  background: #e8eeef;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  background: #52bab3;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.news-input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.news-input label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.contact-input {
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .contact-input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .label,
  .input {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .input {
    flex: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <h1>The Code Review</h1>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="signup">
  <h2>Sign up for our newsletter</h2>
  <p>Get the latest news on how your code is doing right in your inbox</p>
</div>

<form action="index.html" get="post" class="registration-form">
  <fieldset class="first field">
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="mail">Email Address</label>
      <input class="input" type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
      <input class="input" type="tel" id="phone-number" name="user_phone">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="street">Street Address</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" id="street" name="user_street">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="city">City</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" id="city" name="user_city">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="state">State</label>
      <select class="input" id="state" name="user_state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input zip">
      <label class="label zip-label" for="zip">Zip Code</label>
      <input class="input zip-input" type="text" id="zip" name="user_zipcode">
    </div>


  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="second field">
    <legend>Newsletter</legend>

    <p>Select the newspaper you'd like to recieve:</p>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="checkbox" id="html-news" name="user_htm-news" checked></input>
      <label for="html-news">HTML News</label>
    </div>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="checkbox" id="css-news" name="user_css-news">
      <label for="css-news">CSS News</label>
    </div>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="checkbox" id="javascript-news" name="user_javascript-news">
      <label for="javascript-news">Javascript News</label>
    </div>

    <p>Newsletter Format</p>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="radio" id="html" name="user_newsletter-format" checked>
      <label for="html">HTML</label>
    </div>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="radio" id="css-news" name="user_newsletter-format">
      <label for="css-news">CSS News</label>
    </div>

    <p>Other topics you'd like to hear about</p>
    <textarea id="topics" name="user_topics"></textarea>

  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is your use of `flex-grow`.

```
.label,
.input {
    flex: 1; /* flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 0, flex-basis: 0 */
}
.input {
    flex: 3;
}
```

By activating `flex-grow` on both elements in the row, each of them will *always* try to consume all free space in the row. So there's no way an input (or a label) can be shorter, because as long as there is free space, `flex-grow` tells it to occupy that space.

I think you may be better off using `flex-basis`. With this property you have more control over the sizing of flex items.

Make this adjustment to your code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .contact-input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .label,
  .input {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
  .input {
    flex-basis: 75%;
  }
  .zip-input {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: seashell;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

.header-content {
  text-align: center;
  background: #29405a;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #29405a;
}

.signup {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px #29405a dashed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

form {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: #feffff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.field {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px red solid;
}


/*input styles*/

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
textarea,
select {
  background: #e8eeef;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  background: #52bab3;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.news-input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.news-input label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.contact-input {
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .contact-input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .label,
  .input {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
  .input {
    flex-basis: 75%;
  }
  .zip-input {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <h1>The Code Review</h1>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="signup">
  <h2>Sign up for our newsletter</h2>
  <p>Get the latest news on how your code is doing right in your inbox</p>
</div>

<form action="index.html" get="post" class="registration-form">
  <fieldset class="first field">
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="mail">Email Address</label>
      <input class="input" type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
      <input class="input" type="tel" id="phone-number" name="user_phone">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="street">Street Address</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" id="street" name="user_street">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="city">City</label>
      <input class="input" type="text" id="city" name="user_city">
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input">
      <label class="label" for="state">State</label>
      <select class="input" id="state" name="user_state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-input zip">
      <label class="label zip-label" for="zip">Zip Code</label>
      <input class="input zip-input" type="text" id="zip" name="user_zipcode">
    </div>


  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="second field">
    <legend>Newsletter</legend>

    <p>Select the newspaper you'd like to recieve:</p>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="checkbox" id="html-news" name="user_htm-news" checked></input>
      <label for="html-news">HTML News</label>
    </div>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="checkbox" id="css-news" name="user_css-news">
      <label for="css-news">CSS News</label>
    </div>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="checkbox" id="javascript-news" name="user_javascript-news">
      <label for="javascript-news">Javascript News</label>
    </div>

    <p>Newsletter Format</p>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="radio" id="html" name="user_newsletter-format" checked>
      <label for="html">HTML</label>
    </div>

    <div class="news-input">
      <input type="radio" id="css-news" name="user_newsletter-format">
      <label for="css-news">CSS News</label>
    </div>

    <p>Other topics you'd like to hear about</p>
    <textarea id="topics" name="user_topics"></textarea>

  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>

</form>
```

Comment: The total width of both zip elements is now 50% of the row, and `flex-grow` is not in play, so they don't expand to consume the remaining 50% of free space.